# set permission for a website based on joomla 1.7

Tags: php, html, css, joomla, permissions

I have a website based on joomla 1.7. I have defined a super user(admin) and 2 managers (manager 1 and manager 2).

I need each manager to set permissions to access newly created articles. For instance, manager 1 doesn't allow manager 2 to edit, delete or publish his article and vise versa.

The problem is that "Set permissions" button is not always available in article page. It is shown just when the "super admin" option is set to "allowed" in "global configuration" section for manager. 
While I need "super admin" option be set to "denied" so the managers do not gain other rights of super admin and simultaneously the manager can Set Permissions for his created articles.

Please help me with this issue (I know this joomla version is outdated but my site is old and I have to manage it right now).

Comment: Either set it to edit own or have them create articles in separate categories. Or write a plugin to do something customized.

Comment: To explain @Elin's answer, you need to grant the manager group the privilege "edit own" (default setting) but not "edit" all articles (so make this "Denied"), that way each manager will edit their own articles.

Comment: Please make a backup then upgrade to Joomla 2.5, it's painless, are you aware you're vulnerable to really serious exploits?

Answer (score 0):

Joomla's ACL doesn't support the type of settings you're asking for.

As already has been suggested, you would have to create a custom extension to enable this type of flexibility in the security model.

On the subject of the version of Joomla you're using, please be aware that there are major security issues with the 1.7 series and you would be best off updating to the latest 2.5 (which shouldn't cause to many issues unless you have custom code or outdated extensions).

Comment: I'm afraid you're wrong, removing the edit privilege from the managers group is enough achieve this.

Comment: I'm sorry but looking at my stock 2.5 install I can't see a "Set Permissions" button in the front end editor or the backend for a "Manager" user is this something they removed after 1.7?

Comment: No wait. You just set the permissions in the backend to remove the option, then the managers will automatically have no access to the other manager's articles.  It's automatic for them. But reading the question again, it may be required to have it manually set for certain articles only, in which case I'd be wrong :-) but until it's clarified in the question we're at a Schrödingers' moment.